# Installing Anacondas before Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am brand new to Python. I recently installed `python 3.7` and Visual Code. However, I learned that to manipulate data frames and other cool stats stuff, you need Anaconda. So I went and downloaded Anaconda from [here](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/). This link is the directory of Anaconda downloads with different versions for OS. I downloaded the 64-bit Windows `.exe` file.

In installing it, it is asking me two questions with check boxes:

1. Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable

*Not recommended. Instead open Anaconda with the Windows Start menu and select "Anaconda (64-bit)". This "add to PATH" option makes Anaconda get found before previously installed software, but may cause problems requiring you to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda.*

2. Register Anaconda as my default Python 3.7

*This will allow other programs, such as Python tools for Visual Studio PyCharm, Wing IDE, PyDev, and MSI binary packages, to automatically detect Anaconda as the primary Python 3.7 on the system.*

I understand that Question 1 is asking me essentially do you want this version as your default version of Python. My first thought was yes, but then said no, what if Python gets updated.

For Question 2, does Anaconda install its own version of Python? Should I uninstall my version of Python 3.7? What is this asking?

In essence, what do people recommend I check? 1 and 2, just 2, just 1, or none? How do the options differ?

Comment: The Anaconda distribution of Python is convenient and comes packed with and provides easy access to cool stuff, including cool stats stuff, but you do not *need* Anaconda for that.  To the best of my knowledge, there isn't anything that runs on Anaconda but not on other distributions of CPython, and I can't offhand name a Python package that is available through the `conda` package-management system but not through `pip` (though there probably are some).  Anaconda is a convenience, not a necessity.

Comment: You can have both installed without issue. Anaconda comes with many packages already installed and can make things easier, but it isn't required. For example when you talk about data frames you will use Pandas. Anaconda comes with Pandas already installed. If you don't use Anaconda you can install Pandas into a virtual environment with `pip install pandas`. So it is really up to you if you want to use Anaconda or not, and/or make it your default. There is no right or wrong answer here.

Comment: "that to manipulate data frames and other cool stats stuff, you need Anaconda" No, you don't. You need the `pandas` package installed. the Anaconda *Python distribution* comes with `pandas` (and a whole lot of other libraries) pre-installed, along with the virtual-environment/package-management system `conda`. On windows, for this sort of thing, it is generally recommended to simply use the anaconda distribution. If you'd like, go ahead an uninstall the previous installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that Question 1 is asking me essentially do you want this version as your default version of Python.

I guess that depends on what you mean by "default version of Python".  This option will do exactly what it says, and as a result, the Python in the Anaconda distribution will be available to be found via a PATH search, and it will initially appear at the beginning of the PATH.  Subsequent installation of other software could put another Python ahead of Anaconda in the PATH.

> For Question 2, does Anaconda install its own version of Python?

Anaconda *is* Python.  More precisely, Anaconda is a distribution of standard CPython that comes with a bunch of extra packages pre-installed and some convenient extra tools that are specific to it.

> Should I uninstall my version of Python 3.7?

You do not need to uninstall your previous version, but if you select both of the options offered to you then it will probably go largely or completely unused.  One thing to watch out for, though, is that you're installing Anaconda 3 (which packages Python 3) as opposed to Anaconda 2 (which packages Python 2).

> What is this asking?

This alternative provides for a different sense of "default Python" than the other does: it adds or modifies entries in the Windows registry that identify Anaconda as the system's default Python.

> In essence, what do people recommend I check? 1 and 2, just 2, just 1, or none?

I would suggest checking both.  I would furthermore suggest not bothering with another Python, unless you need both a Python 3 and a Python 2.